# Angularytics (Google Analytics for AngularJS directive) only in production environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, angulartics

I´m using Angularytics in my AngularJS web app. It´s working fine, however, I have three environments (development, test and production) and it´s gathering statistics from both of them. I would like to show analytics only for production enviroment.

I have analyzed many options but all of them have some problems. Now, I would like to edit the angularytics.js script to add a condition, so, the code it will only do something in case $rootScope.ENVIRONMENT constant is Production.

Something like:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('angularytics', []).provider('Angularytics', function () {
    if($rootScope.ENVIRONMENT == 'Production') {
    var eventHandlersNames = ['Google'];
    this.setEventHandlers = function (handlers) {
      if (angular.isString(handlers)) {
        handlers = [handlers];
      }
      eventHandlersNames = [];
      angular.forEach(handlers, function (handler) {
        eventHandlersNames.push(capitalizeHandler(handler));
      });
    };
    var capitalizeHandler = function (handler) {
      return handler.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + handler.substring(1);
    };
    var pageChangeEvent = '$locationChangeSuccess';
    this.setPageChangeEvent = function (newPageChangeEvent) {
      pageChangeEvent = newPageChangeEvent;
    };
    this.$get = [
      '$injector',
      '$rootScope',
      '$location',
      function ($injector, $rootScope, $location) {
        var eventHandlers = [];
        angular.forEach(eventHandlersNames, function (handler) {
          eventHandlers.push($injector.get('Angularytics' + handler + 'Handler'));
        });
        var forEachHandlerDo = function (action) {
          angular.forEach(eventHandlers, function (handler) {
            action(handler);
          });
        };
        var service = {};
        service.init = function () {
        };
        service.trackEvent = function (category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction) {
          forEachHandlerDo(function (handler) {
            if (category && action) {
              handler.trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction);
            }
          });
        };
        service.trackPageView = function (url) {
          forEachHandlerDo(function (handler) {
            if (url) {
              handler.trackPageView(url);
            }
          });
        };
        service.trackTiming = function (category, variable, value, opt_label) {
          forEachHandlerDo(function (handler) {
            if (category && variable && value) {
              handler.trackTiming(category, variable, value, opt_label);
            }
          });
        };
        $rootScope.$on(pageChangeEvent, function () {
          service.trackPageView($location.url());
        });
        return service;
      }
    ];
  }});
}());
(function () {
  angular.module('angularytics').factory('AngularyticsConsoleHandler', [
    '$log',
    function ($log) {
      var service = {};
      service.trackPageView = function (url) {
        $log.log('URL visited', url);
      };
      service.trackEvent = function (category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction) {
        $log.log('Event tracked', category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction);
      };
      service.trackTiming = function (category, variable, value, opt_label) {
        $log.log('Timing tracked', category, variable, value, opt_label);
      };
      return service;
    }
  ]);
}());
(function () {
  angular.module('angularytics').factory('AngularyticsGoogleHandler', function () {
    var service = {};
    service.trackPageView = function (url) {
      _gaq.push([
        '_set',
        'page',
        url
      ]);
      _gaq.push([
        '_trackPageview',
        url
      ]);
    };
    service.trackEvent = function (category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction) {
      _gaq.push([
        '_trackEvent',
        category,
        action,
        opt_label,
        opt_value,
        opt_noninteraction
      ]);
    };
    service.trackTiming = function (category, variable, value, opt_label) {
      _gaq.push([
        '_trackTiming',
        category,
        variable,
        value,
        opt_label
      ]);
    };
    return service;
  }).factory('AngularyticsGoogleUniversalHandler', function () {
    var service = {};
    service.trackPageView = function (url) {
      ga('set', 'page', url);
      ga('send', 'pageview', url);
    };
    service.trackEvent = function (category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction) {
      ga('send', 'event', category, action, opt_label, opt_value, { 'nonInteraction': opt_noninteraction });
    };
    service.trackTiming = function (category, variable, value, opt_label) {
      ga('send', 'timing', category, variable, value, opt_label);
    };
    return service;
  });
}());
(function () {
  angular.module('angularytics').filter('trackEvent', [
    'Angularytics',
    function (Angularytics) {
      return function (entry, category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction) {
        Angularytics.trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction);
        return entry;
      };
    }
  ]);
}());
```

I know a little bit of Angular, however, I think I´m not skilled enough to inject the $rootScope in this script. I always get `$rootScope is not defined`.

**UPDATE**
Regarding the comments below, I update the post:
To add the script conditionally was my first approach. This can be done in a controller like:

```
if ($rootScope.ENVIRONMENT == 'Production') {    
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var js = document.createElement("script");    
            js.type = "text/javascript";
            js.src =   "lib/plugins/angularytics-yanpy.js";
            head.appendChild(js);           
        }
```

This is angularytics-yanpy:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-59702007-1', 'auto');
```

In the other hand, you have to add the angularytics script to home page:

```
I think this will work in production environment. However, now in development a got a javascript error. Because angularytics.js needs the ga object created in the angularytics-yanpy.js. As this script is not created because is in development environment a get the javascript error.
```

I also added the `<script src="lib/plugins/angularytics.js"></script>` dinamically. But I got a new error, because this script defines a angularytics provider that is defined in the app.js file.

So, the errors are chained and thats why I tried to update the angularytics.js script in order to keep the provider but in case of environment different that production it should do nothing.

Probably I´m not so clear, but it´s not easy to explain. Just let me know if you need some more clarifications.

Comment: `$rootScope` is not available in configuration phase..and provider gets initialized in config phase

Comment: can you optionally include this script?

Comment: The easy cop-out would be to just let the script run but apply a filter to the Google Analytics data views that includes data only from the production environment.

Comment: If you are developing, do you connect/browse to your client due direct IP or hostname?

Comment: Are you using any build script to build your app?

Comment: Do you mean regading analytics? Yes, as the title says, I´m using Angularytics.

Comment: @rober he means are you using Grunt/Gulp?

Comment: Ok sorry. Yeah, I use grunt, but so far only for building purposes.

Comment: Check my answer. It is exactly what you are after and follows the documentation. All these answers saying "use $rootScope" are completely incorrect and it's such a bad way to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting the environment in the `$rootScope`, it would be best to set it as a constant using grunt-ng-constant ([see tutorial](http://hounddog.github.io/blog/using-environment-configuration-with-grunt/)).

To answer your question. You can inject rootScope into the provider by using:

`.provider('Angularytics', function ($rootScope) {});`

**However** this isn't a good solution to your overall problem.

A good method would be to detect the hostname and set separate **Google Analytic Properties** for:

- development
- staging
- production

In your html google analytics script add this switch statement.

```
var gaProp;

switch (window.location.hostname) {
    case 'www.domain.com':
        gaProp = 'UA-123456'; // production
        break;
    case 'staging.domain.com':
        gaProp = 'UA-654321'; // staging
        break;
    default:
        gaProp = 'UA-000000'; // development
}

// Google Analtics
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', gaProp, 'auto');
```

Note I am setting gaProp in the ga event (last line).

This way you can setup different goals and filters for each property and all your test data doesn't interfere with each other.

Comment: Didn't think about this method, that's another good solution, you get my upvote.

Comment: Yes, definitely I love this approach. This is what I was looking for. Actually the key is to have different tracking codes. I got this key from @Nobita. Just a small question. Can I set up many tracking codes with the same Analyitcs account, or should I create many accounts?

Comment: You keep the same account, but have multiple properties. See my site here http://i.imgur.com/hlcaarx.png The main Account is the company that runs the brand for example, and the properties are the sites/locations of that brand. I think you can have up to 50 on one Account.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set up a filter in the Google Analytics data views.

1. Click on `Add Filter`.
2. Give your filter a name.
3. Set the filter Type to `Custom`.
4. Select the `include` button Set the filter field to `Hostname`.
5. Then set the pattern like so: `www\.yourdomain\.com$` (Of course if
   you don't use '.com' you use the TLD you actually use).
6. Select the profiles for which you would like to enable this filter.

This is probably the easiest way of doing what you want. You filter out any data that is not from the domain.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understando what you mean. Click on Add Filter? Where? Please, take into account, so far I´m trying to use an AngularJs directive for analitycs which is Angularytics. Where should I add the filter?

Comment: Got to the admin page in google analytics. Click on 'All filters', from there on follow my steps above. You can leave your directive as is and keep it running in either production and development environments. Link to google : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Grunt to build your app here's a method I've successfully implemented in one of my apps at work.

I have generated 2 tracking codes in Google Analytics, one for the **testing** environment, one for **production**. I see that you're not planning to track you environment, and that was my initial plan too. However it's good to test that everything is working regarding Google Analytics too, and also it will be very useful in case you'll start tracking custom events (like how many users click on a certain button and so on). Luckily tracking codes are free...

I have used [Grunt preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess) to conditionally write the appropriate code.

In my `index.html` I have placed my GA code at the bottom like so:

```
  <script>
     (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  <!-- @if DEV -->
  ga('create', 'UA-554030000-1', 'auto');
  <!-- @endif -->
  <!-- @if PRODUCTION -->
  ga('create', 'UA-554030000-2', 'auto');
  <!-- @endif -->
  </script>
```

Then simply configure your task:

```
preprocess : {
  html: 'build/index.html',
  options: {
    inline : true
  }
  production : {
  options: {
   context : {
    PRODUCTION: true
   }
  }
 },
 dev : {
  options: {
    context : {
     DEV: true
   }
 }
```

Then running `grunt preprocess:production` or `grunt preprocess:dev` will strip the unused code and build the appropriate file. This task can then be included in your build process (I use a flag like `grunt build --dev` to direct the script to the right path).

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as turning development mode on to stop sending tracking information. Straight from the docs, it says to do the following in your app config.

For the two environments you don't want tracking sent, set to true and when pushing to production just set it back to false using a build script.

```
$analyticsProvider.developerMode(true);
```

Comment: If you combine this with the answer above you can do `$analyticsProvider.developerMode(ENV.name != 'production');`

Comment: correct, can also do it that way if you want to set environment variables in your client side code.

Comment: Hi Joshua, @EdwardKnowles.  This would be great if I were using Angulartics, but I´m using Angularytics (is not the same) :). This makes sense, but I didn´t read anything as this in Angularytics. I can´t move to Angulartics because is not compatible with my AngularJS 1.0.7 version.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just read through the documentation for that. My answer still stands, have a full read through of it and see what you think :)